# Cannot stop Repeating UIView.animateWithDuration (Swift)

Tags: animation, swift, ios8, uiviewanimation, repeat

I'm creating a simple animation of two strokes rising out of a cup of coffee as steam. I've set up an animation of 2 shape layers. I added these two layers to 2 subviews and am using `UIView.animateWithDuration` to animate them up vertically and fade out, with a small offset.

I want this animation to repeat, but only while my button is selected. Using the `UIViewAnimationOptions` i can set the options to `.Repeat`, but then they continue forever. I've tried everything i can think of to stop the animations as you will see at the end of my code, but the animation won't disappear.

I have `var buttonSelected = false`, before my drawing code at the top of my class,  which I am using to check and see if my steam animation should run or not. I'm also using that bool to run a function that returns `.Repeat` or `nil` to my UIView animation options depending on whether or not the button is selected.

Back in my view controller where i set my `buttonSelected` in instances of my steam animation class, I have a function that tells the class `.setNeedsDisplay()`. My understanding is that this function will cause my the instance of my class to refresh itself. This seems to work for updating the color of my Graphic which is modified from within the class, but perhaps I need to call something else to properly refresh the removal of the animations?

```
//Turn steam elements into Shape Layers then into Views
        colorRed.setFill()
        shapePath.fill()
        //Turn steam shapes into shape layers
        var steam1 = CAShapeLayer()
        var steam2 = CAShapeLayer()
        steam1.path = shape2Path.CGPath
        steam2.path = shape3Path.CGPath
        steam1.fillColor = transparent.CGColor
        steam2.fillColor = transparent.CGColor


        //Create the views for the steam
        var steam1View = UIView()
        var steam2View = UIView()
        self.addSubview(steam1View)
        self.addSubview(steam2View)
        steam1View.layer.addSublayer(steam1)
        steam2View.layer.addSublayer(steam2)

        func shouldRepeat()->UIViewAnimationOptions{
            if repeatSteam == true {
                return .Repeat
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }

        }
            //Set initial properties for steam layers & views
            steam1.fillColor = colorRed.CGColor
            steam2.fillColor = colorRed.CGColor
            steam1View.alpha = 1.0
            steam2View.alpha = 1.0
            steam1View.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 20)
            steam2View.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 30)
            //Animate Steam 1
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0.0, options:shouldRepeat(), animations: {
                steam1View.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -10)
                steam1View.alpha = 0.0
                }, completion: nil)
            //Animate Steam 2
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.9, delay: 0.0, options:shouldRepeat(), animations: {
                steam2View.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(5, -10)
                steam2View.alpha = 0.0
                }, completion: nil)


            //Check the buttonSelected state and stop the steam animations if false
            if self.buttonSelected == false {
            //Make smoke transparent
            steam1.fillColor = transparent.CGColor
            steam2.fillColor = transparent.CGColor
            steam1.setNeedsDisplay()
            steam2.setNeedsDisplay()
            println("Smoke should dissapear")
            steam1.hidden = true
            steam2.hidden = true
            self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
            self.layer.setNeedsDisplay()
            //steam2View.layer.removeAllAnimations()
            //Fill cup with green
            colorGreen.setFill()
            shapePath.fill()
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
steam1.layer.removeAllAnimations()
steam1.transform = // reset to original state
steam.alpha = 1 // reset to original alpha level
steam2.layer.removeAllAnimations()
...
```

Your animation might stop somewhere in between animations, so if needed, reset the values.

Answer (score 0):

For UIButton:

```
self.Button.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Comment: Please follow thks [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up